If lord krishna was vegetarian, why did he hunt animals and for what?
I'm no expert in my religion but have a lot of doubts.
Some of them is lord Krishna hunting animals, use of Dholaks made from animal membrane in temples for Kirtans. Is that not hypocrisy

Huh? Why would a Kshatriya... A King at that, be a Vegetarian. Isn't the question self-contradictory.
